# Java Sound Clip fails to play after multiple plays

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, clip

I use Clips in a game. The clips play fine, but after some "shots", the following problem occurs

> Exception in thread "PulseAudio Eventloop Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: drain failed
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.EventLoop.native_iterate(Native Method)
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.EventLoop.run(EventLoop.java:133)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

My code:

```
public static Clip[] sounds;
...
sounds = new Clip[3];
sounds[0] = getClip("gun.wav");
sounds[1] = getClip("click.wav");
sounds[2] = getClip("over.wav");
...
private void playSound(Clip clp) {
        final Clip clip = clp;
        Runnable soundPlayer = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if(clip.isActive() || clip.isRunning()) clip.stop();
                    clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
                    clip.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(soundPlayer).start();
}
public void shoot() { //runs when space is clicked 
if(canShoot) playSound(sounds[0]);
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException is usually caused when a thread is started more than once.

Comment: Not sure how your `getClip()` method is implemented, but you should try not to reuse the clips.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen but the game is exported as applet and I don't want to redownload whole data.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar problem on OS X, where the clip was sometimes not playing if you tried to stop it and restart it from the beginning. I fixed it by calling `flush()` right after `stop()`:

```
if(clip.isActive() || clip.isRunning()) {
    clip.stop();
    clip.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to spawn a background thread to interact with the Clip.  The most commonly used methods of Clip, like "start" and "stop" operate asynchronously, meaning they do not block, so it should be okay to call them from the GUI/AWT/Swing thread.

This page has some reasonable examples:
http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html

I see you are using IcedTea and PulseAudio.  You may experience different behavior when using javax.sound in this JVM, as opposed to the Oracle JVM, since the implementations of javax.sound are significantly different between these two products.

Comment: I actually found a solution: use AudioClip. And calling Clip methods  from default thread resulted in lags.